# No longer get expanded input menu in Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-leopard

For some reason, I no longer see the useful menu items in the Leopard input menu that allow you to enter any unicode character.  Now I only see the keymaps I have active.

How do I get the other items back?

Update: I do not seem to have the options in the International Preferences Pane.  They should, IIRC, be above the list of countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the Character Palette?
Activate it in System Preferences > International > Input Menu.

---

How about this then: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071123103246253

> For some unknown reason, the international data caches can get corrupted and prevent Character Palette and Keyboard Viewer from appearing on the Input tab of the International System Preferences pane. This also breaks the Special Characters entry in the Edit menu of many applications, including the Finder, Safari, and Text Edit.
>
> If this happens to you, go to System/Library/Caches folder and trash the following files (don't worry, they will be re-created when you restart your Mac):

```
com.apple.IntlDataCache.le
com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.kbdx
com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.sbdl
com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.tecx
```

Comment: I think Matthew might mean "Unicode Hex Input", but: it's in the same preference pane, in between the countries.

Comment: Neither of them are in my Prefs Pane: http://www.quicksnapper.com/schinckel/image/missing-input-menu-stuff

Comment: The "Input Type" of the Character Palette is "Palette", so when sorting by Input Type it's somewhere further down.

Comment: It isn't in the list at all.

Comment: see updated answer